# Unhide rows based on a numeric value in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create `Worksheet_Change()` event to unhide rows based on the numeric value of one cell.

I have a table **B13:B513**. I want to unhide a number of rows equal to the value in **C7**. For example, if C7 = 10, then B13:B22 will unhide and the rest will still be hidden.

I have seen several ways of doing something similar but using "case" for each option. In my case I have 500 options. I am sure there is a more efficient way of doing this.

I am using Excel 2010.

Thanks in advance!

Daniel

Comment: is C7 always the cell with number of rows you want to hide ? Does the range of hidden rows starts from row 13 ("B13") ?

Comment: You'll want to check the value in C7 `isnumeric` and then `resize` range B13 to the value in C7 and change the `entirerow`s `hidden` property to False.

Comment: @ongcaps have you tested the code in mu asnwer below ?

Answer (score 0):

The code below on `Worksheet_Change()` event, will run only if the user changes the value in Cell "**C7**", you can modify it easily in the code (it is commeneted at which line).

The code wil unhide the number of rows specified starting from row 13 (according to Range **B13:B513**)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim WatchRange                  As Range
Dim IntersectRange              As Range
Dim Numof_UnhideRows            As Long
Dim UnhideRowStart              As Long


' if you want to unhide the rows in Range(B13:B513) only when someone canges the vlues in C7
Set WatchRange = Range("C7")

' starting unhiding number of rows starting for row 13
UnhideRowStart = 13

Set IntersectRange = Intersect(Target, WatchRange)

If Not IntersectRange Is Nothing Then
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
        Numof_UnhideRows = Target.Value
        Rows(UnhideRowStart & ":" & UnhideRowStart + Numof_UnhideRows - 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False

        MsgBox "Unhide a total of " & Numof_UnhideRows & " rows"
    Else
        MsgBox "Cell C7 doesn't contain a Numeric Value", vbCritical
    End If
Else
   'Do Nothing Spectacular

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd use `Range("B13").Resize(Target.Value).EntireRow.Hidden = False`.  Personal preference though.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook feel free to update my answer if it's improving the answer

Comment: I wouldn't say it's improving - just another way of getting the same result.